# how to use db.find() to retrieve data from mongodb using pymongo

Tags: json, mongodb, twitter, pymongo, hashtag

i am trying to retrieve all those records from mongodb collection "posts" in which number of hashtags are greater than 0
my code is:

```
client = MongoClient()
db = client['test-database']
collection = db['test-collection']
posts = db.posts
for post in posts.find({"entities":{"hashtags":{"$not": {"$size": 0}}}}):
    post
```

the data stored in is of format

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5502eeec63a9f07bf15c0c74"),
        "entities" : {
            "user_mentions" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : 588587397,
                    "indices" : [ 
                        0, 
                        10
                    ],
                    "id_str" : "588587397",
                    "screen_name" : "MehrTarar",
                    "name" : "Mehr Tarar"
                }
            ],
            "symbols" : [],
            "trends" : [],
            "hashtags" : [],
            "urls" : []
        },


        "country_code" : "IN",
        "attributes" : {},
        "id" : "03b7ea94ef68e9d7",
        "name" : "Mylapore Tiruvallike"

}
```

could suggest corrections
python2.7
mongodb3.0

Answer (score 0):

You could try using numeric array indexes in query object keys to determine the array size e.g. this looks for all post documents that have at least a hashtag array element:

```
db.posts.find({"entities.hashtags.0": {$exists: true}})
```